# Xamarin Android Convert Byte array to PDF file

Tags: android, xamarin, arrays, file-handling

I would like convert Byte array to PDF file and stored it to Internal Storage. I am using below mentioned code, it is saying PDF is of invalid format.

```
private void ConvertToFile(string fileName , string filePath,Byte[] Bytes){



        if (!File.Exists (filePath)) {
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Bytes);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is Bytes coming from?  Are you sure that it is a valid PDF file?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it via Android native it works but not with Xamarin. It is coming from WS

Comment: I have a same problem do you found any solution for Xamarin forms?

Answer (score 0):

First you get bytedata from your webservice in your application. then give the respective Absolute path (I have set internal storage path in download folder in my code below). After that **`WriteAllBytes`** is the inbuilt function that convert your bytes to pdf here :

```
 WebService ws= new Android.WebService();
 byte[] getbytedata= ws.YourMethodName();
 string directory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
 string file = Path.Combine(directory, "temp.pdf");
 System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, getbytedata);
```

Hope this will work.